# Using SQL windows functions to write a query the calculates the running total of city populations in a country

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, psql

This is the query I am supposed to be writing using 2 different tables: one called country with all the country names, country populations, and country codes, the other called city with city id, country code, city name, and city population. country code as the primary key of course. The resulting table must print country name as country, city name as city, city population as population and the running total of each city population within a country.

1. Using SQL window functions, write a query that calculates a running total of the sum of all city populations with each country. This running total should be calculated by accumulating the city populations from largest to smallest. The resulting output should be sorted rst by country name and secondarily by the running total column. Also display the city name and city population in each row.

This is what I have which prints the table fine, but the running total column does not work correctly. I need to make sure it sums all of the city's populations within a specific country so that the last city name before the country changes = the country total population. It must be ordered by country name and then the city population or running total.

```
SELECT country.name AS country, 
   city.name AS city, 
   city.population, 
   sum(city.population) OVER (ORDER BY city.population, country.name) 
FROM lab6.country INNER JOIN lab6.city USING (country_code) 
ORDER BY country.name ASC, city.population DESC;
```

Can anyone offer some insight as to why this isn't working and what changes may need to be made?

Comment: Since when are there window functions in mysql? And did you have a look at the tag info of [tag:psql]? What database and version are you on?

Answer (score 2):

You need to PARTITION BY country:

```
SELECT country.name AS country, 
   city.name AS city, 
   city.population, 
   sum(city.population) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY country.name
         ORDER BY city.population DESC
         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM lab6.country INNER JOIN lab6.city USING (country_code) 
ORDER BY country.name ASC, city.population DESC;
```